# Why source is empty object for hook_feeds_after_parse in dpm()?

Tags: feeds, importing-exporting

Working on a module that modifies some CSV files before it's processed
by `feeds_import`. I use the `hook_feeds_after_parse($source, $result)`.
The processing and `$result` is ok.

But the object `$source` of type `FeedSource` is empty!
So how can we know which source is being handled?

Why is it empty?

```
if $source == x: // do that.
```

is not possible.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ooops ok,
`dpm($source)` does not show protected class properties if you don't specify which protected variable you want to display.
You have to point the property you want to display.

After some research in FeedsConfigurable.inc and DB 
`dpm($source->id)` is the unique id (string!) I search for.

/n